# The use of \s in replace vs regular expressions

Tags: regex, replace, newline, whitespace

While learning python I got my first real python stumper when processing a multi line file.  It seems like `\s` in the replace method does not remove newlines, where `\s` remove newlines when used in a regular expressions.   I can remove the newlines using replace `\n` just fine, but I am troubled that the definition of `\s` is different for the replace method and regular expressions.  Is this really the case?

```
s_clean = s.replace('\s', '')

import re
s_clean = re.sub(r'\s', '', s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes `string.replace` is different from `re.sub`.  The former replaces the substrings you ask to replace and the latter replaces substrings which are occurrences of the *pattern* you give it.

This design is intentional, and probably not something that should trouble you.  After all, one is a method on strings, the other is a method on regexes.

Here's another example that you might find interesting:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "aaaa+b"
>>> s.replace("a+", "c")
'aaacb'
>>> re.sub(s, "a+", "c")
'c'
```

I think this is pretty sensible.  Yes it is true that other languages expect either a regex or a string in `replace`, but Python actually keeps them distinct!

Comment: I guess it still seems confusing to have different definitions of \s for replace and re, but now I know the \s is just a space in replace.